# Google Form and Twilio integration

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio-api

I am working on a project and could use some help.
I have Twilio setup, and working. When I text a name to my Twilio number it sends the webhook to my application at home and the name comes up on the screen at the house.
I want to do the same thing, but instead of texting i want to use a google form to send the info to Twilio.
I have the Form set up, and the Sheet that gathers the results. In the sheet I inserted the code that is below, and setup a trigger to execute the code when a new entry is submitted.

When I enter a name in the form, the sheet collects the response, and executes the code.
The log file shows that the request is being made to Twilio and Twilio accepted it, by returning a '200' code.
the response line seems to be blank in the log file, and the name entered in the form never comes through to the screen.
If I text the name from my cell, it comes through right away.

I am hoping that by attaching the code and the log files here, some can see something I may be missing.

```
 CODE:
...
 function onSubmit(e) {
// Replace 'YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID' and 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN' 
with your Twilio credentials
var twilioAccountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var twilioAuthToken = '92xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2';

// Replace 'YOUR_TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID' with your Twilio 
Messaging Service SID
var twilioMessagingServiceSid = 'MGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd9';
// Replace 'RESPONSE_INDEX' with the correct column index for 
Question 1
if (e && e.values) {
var response = e.values[1];
Logger.log("Response from Question 1: " + response);
// Rest of your code
} else {
Logger.log("Form submission event object is undefined or lacks 
'values'.");

 }
 var twilioWebhookUrl = 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:8888/plugin.php? 
 plugin=TwilioControl&page=TSMS.php&nopage=1';

 var payload = {
 body: response,
 };
 var options = {
'method': 'post',
'payload': payload
 };
 // Log before making the POST request to check if it's reached this 
 point
 Logger.log("Before making the POST request.");

  try {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(twilioWebhookUrl, options);
  
  // Log the response from the webhook (optional)
  Logger.log("Webhook Response Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log("Webhook Response: " + response.getContentText());
  
  // Log after making the POST request to check if it's completed
  Logger.log("After making the POST request.");
  
  // Check if the response from Twilio indicates success or contains 
  any error information
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    Logger.log("Webhook request was successful.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("Webhook request failed with status code: " + 
  response.getResponseCode());
  }
  } catch (error) {
  Logger.log("Error while making the POST request: " + error);
  }


  }
 ...
```

LOG FILE:
Deployment  Function  Type      Start Time                Duration    Status
Head        onSubmit Trigger    Sep 8, 2023,1:15:17 PM     0.388 s    Completed

Cloud logs
Sep 8, 2023, 1:15:17 PM Info    Response from Question 1: Bob
Sep 8, 2023, 1:15:17 PM Info    Before making the POST request.
Sep 8, 2023, 1:15:18 PM Info    Webhook Response Code: 200
Sep 8, 2023, 1:15:18 PM Info    Webhook Response:
Sep 8, 2023, 1:15:18 PM Info    After making the POST request.
Sep 8, 2023, 1:15:18 PM Info    Webhook request was successful.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to trigger an HTTP request whenever the form is completed, right? But why do you want to send a text message? Wouldn't it be easier if you directly invoked the HTTP webhook from the form (and save sending the SMS)?

Comment: that would work too. I created this script in Apps Script and I'm not getting any errors on execution, but nothing is coming through to the screen.  how can i post the code for review?

Comment: you can edit the original question and add your code there

Comment: The code seems right. Do you see anything suspicious in the error log of the [debugging tools](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/troubleshooting/debugging-tools#how-to-use-the-twilio-error-logs)?

Comment: Yes, the webhook response code is 200, but then the webhook response line is blank.

Comment: The debugging tools should also show you additional information, i.e. whether the message has been delivered or a status code why not